# how to define multiple object times in map object in Open api yml

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am newbie to openapi . I need some help in writing open api yml 3.0

for below response format

```
{
    “Details”: {
        “detail1”: [
            {
                "id": “idvalue”1,
                “Info”: {
                    “Testinfo1”: "1.0.0",
                    “Testinfo2”: "2.0.0"
                }
            }
        ],
        “Detail2”: [
            {
                "id": “idvalue2”,
                “Info”: {
                    “Testinfo3”: "1.0.0",
                    “Testinfo4”: "2.0.0"                }
            }
        ],
        "Detail3”: [
            {
                “First name”: “firstName,
                “Lastname: “last”Name,
                “Address”: “address”,
                “Dependents”: []
            }
        ]
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": “some url”
        }
    }
}
```

detail1, detail2, detail3 could be different object types or same object types
and there can be any no of details .
I am struck at below points

1. how can i represent map open api
2. how to represent multiple object types with in map.

Answer (score 0):

Check this below YAML snap

```
DetailsSchemaElement:
  type: object
  properties:
    Details:
      type: object
      properties:
        detail1:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              Info:
                type: object
                properties:
                  Testinfo1:
                    type: string
                  Testinfo2:
                    type: string
        Detail2:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
              Info:
                type: object
                properties:
                  Testinfo4:
                    type: string
                  Testinfo3:
                    type: string
        Detail3:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              First-name:
                type: string
              Address:
                type: string
              Dependents:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
              Lastname:
                type: string
    links:
      type: object
      properties:
        self:
          type: object
          properties:
            href:
              type: string
```